# what is SQL ReportServer GetMyRunningJobs in my SQL Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server

While running the SQL Profiler on a client site I noticed `getmyrunningjobs` running over and over bogging down their system in the morning from about 5:30 am to 6:30am.  I know it runs all the time but for some reason it appears to run 4 times in a row every couple of seconds in the morning.  I'm not really sure what it is used for, though I've read a lot on SQL Profiler, I can't find much on SQL Report Server.

Can I stop or change the frequency or is there something else going on that I can check?  Also, what is `Tablockx`, and is this related?

Thanks.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: It's a stored procedure in the ReportServer database. You can open it up and look at it. How did you come to the conclusion that this was responsible for bogging down the system?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your secondary question, `TABLOCKX` is a SQL Server table hint that applies an exclusive table lock. I'd think this would be related to your problem only if something is holding the lock for an unusually long time during the timeframe you indicated.